# Two smiliar pages: Google index the wrong one

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, meta-tags

Good morning On my site I offer a product, let's say "Purchase a car" (obviously it's not that), I was ranked in second position on google for years, then I launched a more specific product (Let's say "purchase a red car") which requires a dedicated page.

The problem is that now, on the keyword "purchase a car", we no longer come across the page on which I was very well referenced and which was an important entry point for my site, but I am referenced on "Purchase of red car" which is on the 7th page and is not a very strategic webpage for me. So how can I ask google to prioritize the first page?

Comment: Do word analysis on both pages anf tweak them. There are online tools for it.

Comment: I did it, but the pages are the same and I can't merge them